# Read CoNLL input with Stanfor-NER

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I'm currently doing a project using Stanford NER and I need to compare the results of Precision, Recall and F1 with different classifiers. My problem is I can't make the classifiers to read the input in CoNLL format (blank line separates different sentences). I've tried to run Stanford NER with

> -readerAndWriter edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.CoNLLDocumentReaderAndWriter

but the output still appears in Non-CoNLL (it uses . to separate sentences instead of blank lines).

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This link should be helpful: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.html#j